# using puppet host resource with hiera data source

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to implement puppet `/etc/hosts` handling using [hiera](http://www.devco.net/archives/2011/06/06/puppet_backend_for_hiera.php) as data 
source, but my current implementation requires data duplication 
because I could pass only array of strings as `$name` to *host* resource.

Is there any way to avoid such data duplication? 
Or maybe it is possible to use templates but keep ability to have local modifications 
to `/etc/hosts` file?

```
class hosts ($hosts = hiera("hosts"), $hostsdefs = hiera("hostsdefs"))  { 

  define hostentry( ) { 
    host{ $name: ip => $hostsdefs[$name][ipaddress], 
                 host_aliases => $hostsdefs[$name][host_aliases]  } 
  } 

  hostentry{ $hosts: } 
}
```

YAML data for hiera:

```
---- 
hosts: 
  - host1.example.com 
  - host2.example.com 
hostsdefs: 
  host1.example.com: 
    ipaddress: 10.0.0.1 
    host_aliases: host1 
 host2.example.com: 
    ipaddress: 10.0.0.2 
    host_aliases: host2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find following solution using `create_resource` function

```
class hosts ($hosts = hiera_hash("hosts"))  {
  create_resources( 'host', $hosts )
}
```

it needs slight modification to my original data (change hash key to `ip` to match resource parameter):

```
---- 
hosts: 
  host1.example.com: 
    ip: 10.0.0.1 
    host_aliases: host1 
 host2.example.com: 
    ip: 10.0.0.2 
    host_aliases: host2
```